# Conditional statement to determine if XML tag contains an element? (XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have two different XML documents below:

**XML 1**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<Match>
    <Trades>
        <Trade fruitId="apples"/>
    </Trades>
</Match>
```

**XML 2**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<Match2>
    <Properties>
        <foobar>123</foobar>
    </Properties>
    <Trades>
        <Trade vegetableId="eggplant"/>
    </Trades>
</Match2>
```

I would like to create one XSLT document which would basically take the value inside of  `fruitId` , or `vegetableId`, depending on which one is available. The XSLT should satisfy both XML1 and XML2.

I am not sure how to approach this, whether or not i should   create an if-statement that checks to see if this Trades tag contains a vegetableId, or FruitId. I am a bit lost here. This is what i came up with so far.

**MY XSLT ATTEMPT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

     <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="Trades/Trade">
         <xsl: if test = "(contains(@fruitId, 'somevalue'))">
              <xsl:value-of select="@fruitId"/>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl: if test = "(contains(@vegetableId, 'somevalue'))">
              <xsl:value-of select="@vegetableId"/>
         </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know that my contains statement has 'somevalue' inside, this is not the acutal code i am running, rather its an idea of what im thinking of trying out, although i am not sure how to approach.

Also,  `<Match>` is different than `<Match2>`.

Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use something like this.
Depending on the document you are passing to the transformation, only one element of the concat() function will be non-empty, so effectively only one value will be present in the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

     <xsl:template match="Trades/Trade">
       <output><xsl:value-of select="concat(@fruitId,@vegetableId)"/></output>
     </xsl:template>
     
     <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here (I merged the two files together to test): https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4up

Comment: Or simply `<xsl:value-of select="@fruitId | @vegetableId"/>`.